# Bias-variance trade-off between LDA and QDA w.r.t. dimensionality

Tags: classification, discriminant-analysis, high-dimensional, bias-variance-tradeoff

Consider the bias-variance trade-off between linear discriminant analysis (LDA) and quadratic discriminant analysis (QDA). Switching from QDA to LDA will generally yield a reduction in variance. The reduction will be large if the sample size is small but not so large if the sample size is large; we find this on p. 153 of James at al. ["An Introduction to Statistical Learning"](https://www.statlearning.com/) (2nd edition):

> Roughly speaking, LDA tends to be a better bet than QDA if there are relatively few training observations and so reducing variance is crucial. In contrast, QDA is recommended if the training set is very large, so that the variance of the classiﬁer is not a major concern, or if the assumption of a common covariance matrix for the $K$ classes is clearly untenable.

I wonder if anything could be said about the reduction in variance w.r.t. dimensionality (rather than sample size) of the data. Will the reduction be larger if $X$ is high dimensional than if $X$ is low dimensional? Or does it not matter?